# Similar tags: "logging", "tracking", "analytics", "reporting", and "statistics" -- merge?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

These tags are very similar:

- [logging](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logging) × 47
- [tracking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tracking) × 123
- [analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytics) × 301
- [reporting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reporting) × 26
- [statistics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) × 87

Should some of them be merged?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, these tags shouldn't be merged because they have different meanings.

Tracking and reporting are just a part of analytics; there is also the analyzing part in analytics. I think analytics is more general than tracking. In general, tracking is for a specific action (a button for instance), analytics is the analysis of traffic for an entire site.

For me, [analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytics) = [tracking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tracking) + [reporting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reporting) + [statistics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics).

Otherwise, tracking and logging have also different meanings for me. You can log actions of a user with never look at into the file to analyze the result.

Comment: I second this answer. They're interrelated, but can be discussed individually too.

Answer (score 1):

"tracking", "analytics", and "reporting" should be merged.  They mean the same thing.  I'm also in favor of including "statistics" in the merge.  It could mean something different, but in the context of a site about being a webmaster, it is talking about website tracking.   The questions tagged with it could fit in the same bucket just fine.  The canonical tag should be [analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytics) because it is the most popular.

Logging is a different concept and should be left separate.